# Batch - Kill Process by User

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple of the same processes running, all by different user names. Is it possible to kill all instances of said process but only for 1 username?

For example as you can see:
http://gyazo.com/85a627dfb9c775841047c4feaca3c8cf

Say I only wanted to kill the process owned by user: TCAGame_Svc50
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Cygwin (I assume this is a Windows issue), then [pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) will handle this.

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the
>   process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout. All the
>   criteria have to match. For example,
>
> pgrep -u root sshd
>
> will only list the processes called sshd AND owned by root.
>
> pkill will send the specified signal (by default SIGTERM) to each process instead of listing them on stdout.

See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19359/alternative-to-pkill-or-pgrep-f-on-cygwin)

Answer (score 0):

**edited** I was not able to get the following code work on my XP (the documentation says it should work, maybe it is my computer), but in windows 7 it works without problems

```
taskkill /im arma2oaserver.exe /fi "username eq TCAGame_Svc50" /f
```

**original answer** More verbose, but worked for me on XP

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "executable=arma2oaserver.exe"
    set "user=TCAGame_Svc50"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('
        tasklist /fi "imagename eq %executable%" /v /fo:csv /nh 2^>nul 
        ^| find /i "%user%"
    ') do taskkill /pid %%~a /f
```

tasklist will retrieve the list of processes based on executable name (`/fi`), in csv format (`/fo:csv`), without headers (`/nh`) and in verbose mode (`v`) to include the user name. The list of processes is filtered via a `find` command to only retrieve the list of processes for the desired user. The resulting list is handled via a `for` command that will use the commas as delimiters and for each of the records, the second field (the processID) will be retrieved. The `taskkill` will terminate the processes using the pid retrieved.